# How to echo a string after sorting it by maximum length

Tags: bash

so I am just learning bash and right now I am trying to write one line codes to solve some problems. So write now I am listing all the users in stampede and trying to get the length and name of the longest string. 
So this is where I am at

```
getent passwd | cut -f 1 -d: | wc -L
```

getent passwd - (too get the userid list), the cut command to get the first userid and then wc -L to get the longest length. Now I am trying to figure out how do I echo that? So any input on that would be awesome thank you!

Comment: What's the output of your first command? An example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: So it prints 14000 userids on the stampede network and it looks like this          asharma2:x:826488:816383:Aakash Sharma:/home1/03350/asharma2:/bin/bash

Comment: provide an example..

Comment: Then is use the cut command to get to the userid I want which is asharma2

Answer (score 1):

To get the name of the user with the longest name, use:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{longest=length($1)>length(longest)?$1:longest} END{print longest}'
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  Tell `awk` to use a colon as the field separator.
- `longest=length($1)>length(longest)?$1:longest`

  For every line of input, this statement is executed. It assigns to the variable `longest` the result of a ternary statement:

  ```
  length($1)>length(longest)?$1:longest
  ```

  This statement tests the condition `length($1)>length(longest)`.  Here, `length($1)` is the length of the name of the current user and `length(longest)` is the length of the longest name seen previously.  If the current name is longer, the ternary expression returns the current name, `$1`.  Otherwise, it returns the previous longest name, `longest`.
- `END{print longest}`

  After we have finished reading the file, this prints the name that was the longest.

Comment: Hey so I spent the longest time trying to read this awk command and still kind of confused. I understand your if statement and that makes complete sense thank you. But what does that awk command really mean?

Comment: To summarize, `awk` reads through each line of the file.  That ternary (`if`) statement keeps track of the longest name.  At the end, that name is printed.  (If you understand the `if` statement, then you understand the most complicated part.)

Comment: So the command of -F the colon is the end of each line in the files? Sorry for the questions just trying to see everything in the code so I can use it properly

Comment: Questions are good.  `-F:` has the same meaning for `awk` as `-d:` did for `cut`.  It tells `awk` to divide the line up into fields with `:` as the field separator.  Thus, the value of the name ends up in `$1`.  The second entry, the one for password, goes in `$2`, the user ID goes in `$3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, that doesn't stray too far from what you have, is to use sed to only output lines that are at least as long as the length you get from your command above:

```
getent passwd | cut -f 1 -d: | sed -n /^.\\{`getent passwd | cut -f 1 -d: | wc -L`\\}/p
```

This will output all users which tie for the longest length.

You can make it a little nicer by storing the list of names in a variable:

```
u=`getent passwd | cut -f 1 -d:`; sed -n /^.\\{`wc -L <<< "$u"`\\}/p <<< "$u"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
getent passwd | cut -f 1 -d: | perl -ne 'print length($_).":$_"'| sort -n| cut -f 2 -d:
```

We create a list `<length>:<username>` with perl, sort by length and print only username.